# SQLITE cant upgrade read-only database from version 1 to 2

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I know there's loads of other posts about this but cant find an answer. I'm following the asset helper guide on github [HERE](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/tree/master/samples/database-v2-upgrade)

I suspect its an SQL syntax error

**LOG**

```
02-19 22:26:18.071  28023-28023/com.calvert.adam.lolinformer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.calvert.adam.lolinformer, PID: 28023
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.calvert.adam.lolinformer/com.calvert.adam.lolinformer.championsActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 1 to 2: /data/data/com.calvert.adam.lolinformer/databases/champions.db
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 1 to 2: /data/data/com.calvert.adam.lolinformer/databases/champions.db
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:266)
        at com.calvert.adam.lolinformer.myDBHelper.getChampions(myDBHelper.java:19)
        at com.calvert.adam.lolinformer.championsActivity.onCreate(championsActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
```

**SQL To update**

```
ALTER TABLE Champions RENAME TO Champions_ME_TMP;
CREATE TABLE Champions (
_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
champ_splash blob NOT NULL,
Name TEXT(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (_id)
);
INSERT INTO Champions  ("_id", "champ_splash", "Name") SELECT "_id", "champ_splash", "Name" || ' ' || "Name" FROM "Champions_ME_TMP";
DROP TABLE Champions_ME_TMP;
```

**DBHelper Class**

```
 public class myDBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "champions.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public myDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public Cursor getChampions() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "Name"};
        String sqlTables = "Champions";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
                null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;

    }


}
```

changing the version number auto calls the assethelper to trigger the update

**EDIT**

I've just done it the lazy way by calling the setForcedUpgrade method to force the database to update

Comment: What are the `||` for in the query??

Comment: @dub stylee i was asking that myself but its in the assethelper tutorial sql file

Comment: Try just using `SELECT "_id", "champ_splash", "Name" FROM ....`

Comment: @dub stylee same error

Comment: How are you calling the SQL?  Directly from SQLite, or in code somewhere?

Comment: @dub stylee its my understanding that my dbhelper class extends sqliteassethelper class which takes care of it.

Comment: Try posting the relevant code where this is being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database is trying to update it's version, but since upgrading is a writing operation it can not be done on the read only database you are requesting, hence the error.

```
public Cursor getChampions() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.close();
    db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    ....
}
```

This will create a writable database first, upgrade the database, and then you can use a read-only database.
Note that after running this code you can remove those lines.