# how to upgrade database version with new rows with SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade

i have developed a tutorial app in which i have saved more than 500 questions and answers.
their is one more table called favourites. which is for user input.
now, i want to update my app with new questions and answers.
but i dont want to erase the data of favourites table (in case, user has marked some questions favourites, so those questions should not be erased from favourites)

so how can i do it?
because, i have used SQLassethelper library for database connectivity.

---

my old db contains:

1. data table(static table)
2. favourites table(local table)

so, according to sqliteassethelper documentation i added my new db:
that contains: updated data table. i didnt inserted favourites table here coz it will be created in script file. 
and stored that db in assets>>databases folder.

then
i created a script fild
db.db_upgrade_1-2.sql

```
alter table "favourites" rename to "favourites_tmp";
create table "favourites" (
"id" Integer not null primary key autoincrement unique,
"question" text,
"answer" text,
"category" text,
"catid" integer
);
insert into "favourites" ("id","question","answer","category","catid") select from "favourites_tmp" "id","question","answer","category","catid" from "favourites_tmp";
drop table "favourites_tmp";
```

so i think here favourites table will be created with old data.
but 
when i run the project, it says: no such tabld favourites.

Comment: There is a section in the [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) README concerned with upgrades.

Comment: but i dont want to alter the table. i just want to insert more data (rows) into a specific table

Comment: and i read readme file, it contains info about altering table.

Comment: i have saved my .db file in assets/databases folder

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/README.markdown) tells you to

> create a text file containing all required SQL commands to upgrade the database from its previous version to it's current version.

You can use *any* SQL commands, not only ALTER TABLE, but also INSERT.

The database file in the assets folder is used only if there is no old data (if the app is installed for the first time). If there is old data, `SQLiteAssetHelper` executes the SQL upgrade script instead.

The SQLiteAssetHelper project contains [an example](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/tree/master/samples/database-v13-upgrade/src/main/assets/databases) that shows how such a script would look like.

To keep the data in the favourites table, you do not need to do anything.
To add the new question/answers, use a bunch of INSERT statements.
(For how to get those INSERT statements, see [How to compare two SQLite databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093263/how-to-compare-two-sqlite-databases-on-linux).)

Comment: means if i have more 100 new questions n answers then i have to write 100 insert queries i that file?

Comment: No, such tedious tasks are better left to the computer. If you want to know how, that would be a different question.

Comment: i tried this method: >>> db.execSQL("attach database ? as old_db", new String[]{database_name_old});.       db.execSQL("insert into "+database_name_new+".favourites " +" select * from old_db.favourites");

Comment: but still its erasing local data...why?

Comment: That is not how you would do the upgrade. (It's not a text file containing SQL commands.) See [How to compare two SQLite databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093263/how-to-compare-two-sqlite-databases-on-linux).

Comment: i am not getting what you are saying

Comment: With SQLiteAssetHelper, you must not override `onUpgrade`; you create an SQL script (a text file) as described in the documentation,

Comment: yes i created it.but will you plz tell me one thing

Comment: how can i write a insert query in that file to copy all data from old table n insert it into new one

Comment: i created same file as described in doc. but it throws error: no such table found

Comment: plz see my updated question. i have followed sqlite asset helper doc. but it gives me error.plz re read my question

Comment: That script is pointless (it does not change anything), and `select from` is not valid SQL. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

finally i got answer for my questions.
as i said i am using SQLiteAssetHelper library.
and now i want to add new records and want to release the update version.
so i was finding the feature by which i can store new updated db in assets folder. and this library will update the old db in user's phone. with keeping particular table in old db.

but currently this library doesnt offers such feature.
the upgrade script can be use only to make changes is old db. we can add new updated db and copy the data from new one.

if we want to add new data and also dont want to erase local data table.
then we need to write insert queries in upgrade script as described in documentation of that library.

but if we have to add 100 queries then their is no shortcut for it.
we have to write 100 insert statements in upgrade script.

and in case if we gate a error saying
cannot upgrade read only database from version x to y then
here is the solution for it:

[SQLITE cant upgrade read-only database from version 1 to 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618558/sqlite-cant-upgrade-read-only-database-from-version-1-to-2)